# how can I filter model of server?

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I am trying to query a servers Model and based on a specific type of model then run some other code.

I have done the below but the server I ran it on is not a `Gen9` but `VMware` so, the result is coming back as the `Else` statement in the below - which is incorrect result I expect.

If I run debugging then `colItems` is empty (ie this is true since the server I ran is VMWare) - is my statement of this the problem - ie, I think it should not be nothing but cannot find out what else I can change it to? `If colItems Is Nothing Then`

```
    strComputer = "."
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem Where Model Like 'Gen9%'")

    If colItems Is Nothing Then
         WScript.Echo "This is not a Gen9 Server"
    Else
        WScript.Echo "This IS a Gen9 Server"
    End If
```

RESULT: (this is not correct result I am expecting)

```
D:\>cscript Intel_Teaming_Install.vbs
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

This IS a Gen9 Server
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter if the server matches or not the query. The `objWMIService.ExecQuery` call will always (if there are no errors) return a collection. This collection will hold the matching instances or will be empty (no items in the collection).

In your case

```
If colItems.Count < 1 Then 
     WScript.Echo "This is not a Gen9 Server"
Else
    WScript.Echo "This IS a Gen9 Server"
End If
```